# How to clear Adobe Acrobat clipboard?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, clipboard

I'm trying to automate certain tasks but I'm having trouble figuring out how to clear the Adobe Acrobat clipboard. (I'm using Pro DC if that matters.)

What I do:

1. Go to "Edit object".
2. Select an object on page (e.g. a chunk of text or an image).
3. Hit Ctrl+C to copy. The chunk of text/image is now on the Adobe Acrobat clipboard.
4. **Now I want to get rid of this text/image that is on the Adobe Acrobat clipboard. How do I do this?**

(The reason is that I want to make sure that when I next hit Ctrl+V, nothing is pasted.)

(I've found ways to clear the Windows clipboard, but this seems to be different from the Adobe Acrobat clipboard.)

Comment: [This](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/440773) was the first search result

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes I saw that and got really excited too. But if you look at the top you'll notice that's for the Photoshop Macintosh forum. There is no Edit > Purge option in Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: This would appear to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - why would you want to use Paste if you don't intend for anything to be pasted?

Comment: @Tetsujin: I am trying to write a script where I copy an object on a page, then paste it. However, occasionally there is no object to be copied and so I don't want anything to be pasted. But with the clipboard not cleared, the script pastes whatever's on the clipboard (that was left over from the last copy).

Comment: OK, then in that case I'd be looking for the error on Copy rather than Paste - though idk how you would achieve that; idk what language you're automating in.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I'm simply using AutoHotKey. I'm trying to figure out a way to get rid of watermarks on PDFs (something that no one seems to have figured out). In this case the watermark is behind another object (block of text or image), so I want to cut out that object first, select the watermark, delete it, then paste back the object. But sometimes there is no object, so I don't want to be pasting something I copied from another page.